# How can I put the commas for urls when i need 3 different on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-staticfiles

### How can I put the commas?

I'm trying to insert an image with a JavaScript append function. 
Loading the static folder from Django and I can't quotation the url image (needed where are ##) because I'm using '' to delimit the line of js and "" to delimit src="" tag for html:

```
'<a href="#" class=""><img src="{% static ##images/img_1.jpg## %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid coche-img"></a>'
```

What can I do? 
Can I put 3 different commas?

Comment: How about backticks?

Comment: Just put the double quotes `"` Django templating is smart enough to handle that. Although as an advice why even render this url into javacsript, just render it as some attribute on some element in the html and get it from there. Generally it is a bad idea to render from Django into javascript.

Comment: You can always escape the quotation marks (e.g. `const wheather = 'It\'s raining!'`). In your case, it would be `'<a href="#" class=""><img src="{% static \'images/img_1.jpg\' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid coche-img"></a>'`